# Docker CE on Mac OSX hanging on startup

Tags: macos, docker

I had docker working and then I went and upgraded the version by downloading the latest Docker CE dmg from docker.com and installing over the old version. Since then I have been unable to get the Docker app to start.

Double-clicking it would make a spinning beach ball of death appear when hovering over the tray area where the docker icon should open. After a few seconds the activity monitor would list Docker as "not responding".

Attempting to start the app via the command line as sudo gives the following error:

`/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS: sudo ./Docker
json error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}
kern.hv_support: 1`

And the process still hangs.

Mac OS Info

```
El Capitan
10.11.6 (15G1217)
```

Latest Docker version at the time:

```
Version 17.03.0-ce-mac2 (15654)
Channel: stable
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the docker app. I could not use a Factory Reset on Docker since it never fully started. I have tried uninstalling, rebooting, and reinstalling. I have tried to removing the `~/Library/Containers/com.docker*` directories.  I've removed all of the docker links in `/usr/local/bin`. I've tried going back to older versions of Docker such as 1.12.6.14937. I've tried the edge version of the latest Docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to get Docker working with the latest version of Docker by doing the following:

- Uninstall Docker from Applications
- Using CCleaner to look at the startup items and remove the `com.docker.vmnetd` entry. << this seems to be the key thing I hadn't done before!!!
- Reboot the computer
- Reinstall Docker
- Launch Docker
- Enter admin password
- Sacrifice a chicken
- Profit

Comment: so many step, it shouldn't be that annoying. 2018-5-18, I also have this problem(open Docker and it would freeze) macOS 10.13.4
Docker sucks on macos